# Updating model when selected item is deleted

Tags: angularjs

So in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/y67Ex1OA4eajelOWQIO7?p=preview) I have a simple select

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
    <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
</select>
```

With three colors and a button to delete the last one

```
<button ng-click="delRed()">Delete red</button><br/>
```

JS code looks like that

```
angular.module('selectExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [
    {name:'black'},
    {name:'white'},
    {name:'red'},
  ];
  $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red
  $scope.delRed = function(){        
    $scope.colors.length = 2;
  }
}]);
```

When red is selected and clicking on "Delete red " the `-- choose color --` option is selected, but the model `{{myColor}}` is

```
{"name":"red"}
```

how can I set it to null (or empty string or any "empty" value) in case red was selected and is deleted in order to have it coherent with  value?

Comment: You would need to set `$scope.myColor ="";` in the same method...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just override the `myColor` if it is equal to the element you are deleting?

```
  $scope.delRed = function(){
    if ($scope.myColor === $scope.colors[$scope.colors.length - 1]) {
      $scope.myColor = undefined;
    }
    // IMO Overriding .length of an array to delete an element is a bit of a hack
    $scope.colors = $scope.colors.slice(0, $scope.colors.length - 1);
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/YEOwFcrV9OoV4jI8Zlmn?p=preview

---

**Update:** This has been [reported as a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6379) in the framework. The [example for select on Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) also shows the same behavior as the above program. There is an outdated [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/6515) to address the issue as well.

Comment: I thougt of that, but is this the way AngularJS is supposed to work? If I need to write specific logic to update model when the <select> is modified, am I not missing the whole point of Angular? :) Maybe this specific case is a limitation of the framework?

Comment: This has been [reported as a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6379) in the framework. The [example for select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) also shows the same behavior as your program. There is an outdated [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/6515) to address the issue as well.